# Pre-populated recipient in Android email?

Tags: android, email, gmail

I am making an application where the user will click on contact us section and it will open the built-in Gmail application and I have the code to pre-populate the subject and message body in the mail.

I want the code to pre-populate the "To: " section where we add the recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the intent you use to populate the subject and message, add the following:

```
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "youremail@domain.com" });
```

Check the documentation for [`EXTRA_EMAIL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL)

Answer (score 1):

That didn't work for me but this did

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?to="+emailaddress+"&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body);   
intent.setData(data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps someone else out there